# Upgrading rails from 5.0.2 to 5.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to upgrade my current `rails 5.0.2` version to the latest `rails 5.1.0` version by running `bundle update rails` after adding `gem 'rails', '~> 5.1'` on my `Gemfile` and I got this error message.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
      activejob (= 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        globalid (>= 0.3.6) was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
          activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.6.1, which depends on
  activesupport (< 5.1, >= 3.0.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.1.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.1.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
    rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      activesupport (< 6.0, >= 4.2.0)

rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.2.0, which depends on
    activesupport (>= 4.0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you need to try and upgrade to a newer version of jbuilder. However, looking at RubyGems the current dependancies for Jbuilder still say:

> activesupport < 5.1, >= 3.0.0

IF this is the case, JBuilder doesn't yet support the more recent Activesupport, now required by Rails 5.1 - so perhaps JBuilder isn't yet available in Rails 5.1.

If you need to get the newer Rails, then you should probably consider:

- Checking to see if there is a roadmap in JBuilder for this.
- Raising a JBuilder ticket requesting support for that later Rails version.

You could try an override - since it may potentially just work, and that <5.1 is just since it's not yet been tested with the more recent version - just be prepared for glitches if there are genuine compatibility issues. I'd definitely rerun the whole of your test suite after trying that.

The alternative is to wait a little bit - this is a very fresh release - give other packages a chance to catch up with it.

Comment: Yeah I agree on waiting a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting Gemfile.lock then running bundle worked for me

Comment: That is way to risky for a long running project. That will upgrade every gem that is not pinned down.